# Why Vue click event works only one time? Click event works one time ana not working any more

Tags: vue.js

Why Vue click event works only one time? Click event works one time ana not working any more.

I created a an click event that would open a modal coponent, click event works one time and stops.
I'm using Tailwind as third-party library

Modal.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="modal" v-if="isModalActive == true">
    <div class="modal-wrapper shadow-md rounded-sm">
      <CloseIcon
        class="absolute right-5 top-5 w-[30px] h-[30px] text-gray-500 hover:text-red-400 cursor-pointer"
        @click="isModalActive = false"
      />
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="modal-intraday-updates p-10">
          <slot></slot>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import CloseIcon from "./icons/CloseIcon.vue";

export default {
  name: "Modal",
  components: {
    CloseIcon,
  },
  props: {
    isModalActive: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit("close");
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Home.vue

```
<template>    <Modal :isModalActive="isModalActive" @close="isModalActive = false">
    <div>Modal Content </div>
  </Modal>
    <span @click.prenvet="isModalActive = true" class="cursor-pointer">OPEN MODAL</div></template>


<script setup>
import Modal from "../components/Modal.vue";

const isModalActive = ref(false);
const openModal = () => {
  isModalActive.value = true;
};
</setup>
```

Comment: I suppose it depends on the code and your implementation.  If you provide the details, others may be able to help.  Review the guide on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank @yoduh for the answer,  how you got any idea?

Comment: Without knowing anything about your code, it's very hard to guess. There could be a million reasons for broken code.  Can you maybe include the code in your question?  A [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) goes a long way in helping explain an issue.  Without that, all I can say is to check your browser's dev console for any error message before/after firing your click events.

Comment: I edited the question can you control it? As I understood, the isModalActive is not assigning synchronously between two separate components. How can they communicate it?

Comment: Was this code copy/pasted from your actual project?  There's a lot of syntax errors and typos that would prevent this code from running.  Please make sure your code is accurate before posting!

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if you didn't see an error in your browser's dev console. [This is where errors will show up during runtime](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/). The error you *should* see is:

> [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "isModalActive"

I know this because I ran your code (after fixing some typos/syntax errors)

The error tells us exactly what's wrong. Props should only be used for [one-way data flow](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow), meaning once a component receives a prop, it should **not** attempt to change the value of the prop.

```html
<CloseIcon
        class="absolute right-5 top-5 w-[30px] h-[30px] text-gray-500 hover:text-red-400 cursor-pointer"
        @click="isModalActive = false"
      />
```

`isModalActive` is being mutated right here by being set to false. This is causing your error. To prevent this error, have the parent component (Home.vue) mutate the prop for you. In your case, you actually already have most of the code for this in place. Just change your click event to this:

```js
@click="close"
```

which will call your `close` method:

```js
close() {
    this.$emit("close");
},
```

This method emits the event "close" which your parent component will catch, and in fact you already have your parent component doing this:

```html
<Modal :isModalActive="isModalActive" @close="isModalActive = false">
```

So for your problem you just need to change your `@click` as noted above.

Comment: Thank you very much, bro! It worked. I don't know why but surprisingly I was not getting any errors! I'm looking for the reason now. 

Thanks for your help.